# How to segue to one of several subtypes of UIViewController with a storyboard?

Tags: ios, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have a table whose detail-disclosure buttons bring up a `MyDetailViewController` and in `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` I have been setting a few variables. But it turns out that I need something more complex: I need *subtypes* of `MyDetailViewController` (`MyFooController : MyDetailViewController`, `MyBarController : MyDetailViewController`, etc.) based on what row is selected.

My first thought was to assign to the `destinationViewController` in the `UIStoryboardSegue` in `performSegueWithIdentifer:sender:` but that is a read-only variable.

Is there an easy way to do this with Storyboards? Should I create a custom Segue? Or should I just do it programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use multiple segues, one for each of your subtypes of controllers, there is no actual limit to how many you can use from one viewController, or you can, depending on the cell that was selected, instantiate a view controller, and push it on the stack manually, something in the lines of:

```
MyBarController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myBarController"]; // You set the identifiers in the storyboard itself
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking of when I said "do it programmatically." I was wondering if there was a way to do it using the Storyboards visual design surface.

Comment: That's where the multiple segues come into play. Make one segues for each of your destination controllers, and invoke them depending on which one you need at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can't connect multiple segues to a detail-disclosure button, but you can connect as many segues as you want from the controller. Implement tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:, and that method will be called when a user taps the button. You can use the indexPath argument to decide which segue to execute, and then invoke the segue using performSegueWithIdentifier.

Answer (score 0):

As a third alternative, you could create different prototype cells in the storyboard, give each a different `reuseIdentifier`, and create the different segues from each prototype cell.  Then in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, select the correct `reuseIdentifier` when dequeue-ing cells, according to the row.